# How to turn off WPF DataGrid sorting when grouping is turned on?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, collectionviewsource

If I sort one column in DataGrid (which ItemsSource is bound to CollectionViewSource) and turn grouping on in ViewModel

```
MyCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Table"));
```

i get exception:

> Unhandled exception in command handler 'GroupDataGrid' System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array. ---> System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.

However before adding the GroupDescription I try to remove sorting:

```
MyCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.Clear();
```

For some reason this is not enough. Stacktrace:

```
at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
  at MS.Internal.Data.SortFieldComparer.Compare(Object o1, Object o2)
  at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.SwapIfGreaterWithItems(Int32 a, Int32 b)
  at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.PickPivotAndPartition(Int32 lo, Int32 hi)
  at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.IntroSort(Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Int32 depthLimit)
  at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.IntrospectiveSort(Int32 left, Int32 length)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Array.SorterGenericArray.IntrospectiveSort(Int32 left, Int32 length)
  at System.Array.Sort(Array keys, Array items, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer comparer)
  at System.Array.Sort(Array array, IComparer comparer)
  at MS.Internal.Data.SortFieldComparer.SortHelper(ArrayList al, IComparer comparer)
  at MS.Internal.Data.DataExtensionMethods.Sort(IList list, IComparer comparer)
  at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.PrepareLocalArray()
  at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.RefreshOverride()
  at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshInternal()
  at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshOrDefer()
  at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.SortDescriptionsChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.ComponentModel.SortDescriptionCollection.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index)
  at System.ComponentModel.SortDescriptionCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, SortDescription item)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SynchronizeCollections[T](NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, Collection`1 origin, Collection`1 clone)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SortDescriptionsChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.ComponentModel.SortDescriptionCollection.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index)
  at System.ComponentModel.SortDescriptionCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, SortDescription item)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)
  at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.AddGroupingSortDescriptions()
  at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnItemsGroupDescriptionsChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.SynchronizeCollections[T](NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, Collection`1 origin, Collection`1 clone)
  at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.OnInnerGroupDescriptionsChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
  at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
  at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
  at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChange(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
```

EDIT: Code added by reaquest. SetValue in BindingSource/ViewModel classes results in PropertyChanged event.

class for row:

```
public class SelectedNetObjectBindingSource : NetObjectBindingSource
{
    public SelectedObjectsTableGroupBindingSource Table { get; set; }

    public SelectedNetObjectBindingSource(NetObject netObject, SelectedObjectsTableGroupBindingSource table)
        : base(netObject)
    {
        Table = table;
    }
}
```

its parent class:

```
public class NetObjectBindingSource : BindingSource
{
    public NetObject Data { get; protected set; }

    public NetObjectBindingSource(NetObject netObject)
    {
        Data = netObject;
    }
}
```

class for groupheader:

```
public class SelectedObjectsTableGroupBindingSource : GroupHeaderBindingSource
{
    public NetObjectTableId TableId { get; private set; }

    public SelectedObjectsTableGroupBindingSource(NisTable nisTable, GroupHeadersInfo headersInfo)
        : base(nisTable.TableId.ToString(), nisTable.Description, headersInfo)
    {
        TableId = nisTable.TableId;
    }
}
```

it's parent class:

```
public class GroupHeaderBindingSource : BindingSource, IGroupHeader, IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public int GroupedCount { get; set; }

    private GroupHeadersInfo _headersInfo;

    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (SetValue(ref _isExpanded, value))
            {
                NisDllInterface.SetUserSetting(_headersInfo.GroupSection, Name, value ? "True" : "False");
                _headersInfo.UpdateExpandedInfo(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public GroupHeaderBindingSource(string name, string description, GroupHeadersInfo headersInfo)
    {
        _headersInfo = headersInfo;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        var value = UserSettings.Instance.GetSetting(headersInfo.GroupSection, Name);
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.Equals("False"))
            {
                IsExpanded = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IsExpanded = true;    
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null && obj is GroupHeaderBindingSource)
        {
            var groupHeader = (GroupHeaderBindingSource) obj;
            return Description.CompareTo(groupHeader.Description);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    public ICollectionView SelectedObjectItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedObjectsView;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ref _selectedObjectsView, value);
        }
    }


    public bool AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _areSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ref _areSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, value);
            if (_areSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable)
                SelectedObjectItems.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Table"));
            else
                SelectedObjectItems.GroupDescriptions.Clear();

            SaveObjectsSetting(GroupedSettingName, _areSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable ? "True" : "False");
            SelectedObjectsGroupHeaders.IsGrouped = value;
            SelectedObjectItems.Refresh();
            CallAfterSelectedObjectsRefresh(new GroupedRowsRefreshedEventArgs(
                _areSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable ? GroupedGrid.Grouped : GroupedGrid.Ungrouped));
        }
    }

// in viewmodel constructor
SelectedObjectItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new List<NetObject>());


    public void RefreshSelection()
    {
        RefreshSelectionObjects();
        Selection = GetSelectedObjects();

        // Selected objects
        if (SelectedObjectsExpanded)
        {
            IsFetchObjectsAnywayVisible = false;
            bool isTooManyObjects = SelectedObjectsInstance.Count > MaxSelectedObjectCount;
            if (isTooManyObjects && !_fetchObjectsAnyway)
            {
                SelectedObjectsInfoPanelText = App.Current.Resources["MmsMsgTooManyObjectsSelectd"].ToString();
                SelectedObjectItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new List<NetObject>());
                ShowSelectedObjectsInfoPanel = true;
                IsFetchObjectsAnywayVisible = true;
            }
            else if (SelectedObjectsInstance.Count == 0)
            {
                SelectedObjectsInfoPanelText = App.Current.Resources["NisStrNoObjectsSelected"].ToString();
                SelectedObjectItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new List<NetObject>());
                ShowSelectedObjectsInfoPanel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SelectedObjectItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GetSelectedObjects().ToList());
                if (_areSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable)
                    SelectedObjectItems.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Table"));
                else
                    SelectedObjectItems.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
                ShowSelectedObjectsInfoPanel = false;
            }
            _selectedObjectsRefreshSkipped = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _selectedObjectsRefreshSkipped = true;
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
            <DataGrid Name="SelectedObjectsGrid"
                      Visibility="{Binding ShowSelectedObjectsInfoPanel, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedObjectItems}"
                      SelectionMode="Extended"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      Grid.Row="0"  Margin="0,0,4,0">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="SelectedObjectRowContextMenu" 
        DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrKeepSelectionTableShort}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler KeepTable}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrRemoveSelectionTableShort}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler RemoveTable}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrList}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ToggleSelectedObjectsGrouping}" CommandParameter="False" 
                                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image>
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <DrawingImage>
                                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black"
                                                                 Geometry="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBoolToGeometryConverter}}" />
                                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                        </DrawingImage>
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrGroup}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ToggleSelectedObjectsGrouping}" CommandParameter="True"
                                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image>
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <DrawingImage>
                                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black"
                                                                 Geometry="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGeometryConverter}}" />
                                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                        </DrawingImage>
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <Separator Visibility="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrHintTreeExpandAll}"  Command="{ui:CommandHandler ExpandOrCollapseAll}" CommandParameter="True" 
                                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.SelectedObjectsGroupHeaders.DoCollapsedGroupsExist, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameToBitmapSource}}" DataContext="BmpTreeExpandAll"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrHintTreeCollapseAll}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ExpandOrCollapseAll}" CommandParameter="False"  
                                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.SelectedObjectsGroupHeaders.DoExpandedGroupsExist, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameToBitmapSource}}" DataContext="BmpTreeCollapseAll"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Style}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource SelectedObjectRowContextMenu}" />
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="SelectedObjectsRow_DoubleClick" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{ui:CommandHandler ObjectsGridSelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems,ElementName=SelectedObjectsGrid}">
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Name.IsExpanded}"
                                                      Tag="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                                      Background="#FF112255" BorderBrush="#FF002255"
                                                      Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                                                                                   <Expander.ContextMenu>
                                                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrKeepSelectionTableShort}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler KeepTable}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" />
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrRemoveSelectionTableShort}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler RemoveTable}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" />
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrList}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ToggleSelectedObjectsGrouping}" CommandParameter="False" >
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Image>
                                                                    <Image.Source>
                                                                        <DrawingImage>
                                                                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, 
                                                                                    Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBoolToGeometryConverter}}" />
                                                                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                                                        </DrawingImage>
                                                                    </Image.Source>
                                                                </Image>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                        <Separator Visibility="{Binding DataContext.AreSelectedObjectsGroupedByTable, Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrHintTreeExpandAll}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ExpandOrCollapseAll}" CommandParameter="True" 
                                                                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.SelectedObjectsGroupHeaders.DoCollapsedGroupsExist, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameToBitmapSource}}" DataContext="BmpTreeExpandAll"/>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource XpStrHintTreeCollapseAll}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler ExpandOrCollapseAll}" CommandParameter="False"  
                                                                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.SelectedObjectsGroupHeaders.DoExpandedGroupsExist, 
                                                            Source={x:Reference SelectedObjectsGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameToBitmapSource}}" DataContext="BmpTreeCollapseAll"/>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                    </ContextMenu>
                                                </Expander.ContextMenu>
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <DockPanel>
                                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name.Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                                            <Run Text=" ("/>
                                                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name.GroupedCount, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                                            <Run Text=")"/>
                                                        </TextBlock>
                                                    </DockPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <Expander.Content>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                </Expander.Content>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource XpStrLabel}" Binding="{Binding Data.Label}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource XpStrClass}" Binding="{Binding Data.Class.Name}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Did you try implementing `IComparable` on the elements in the array? Assuming you can figure out which array it's talking about. But you can observe a lot by looking at the watch window.

Comment: Grouping and Sorting belongs to View not view model, then you can use it with `xaml` instead of code behind. I have been using it with Lists and DataTables and it always worked. Can you show us how you  create the `CVS` from start to `Binding` point?

Comment: i didn't try implementing IComparable because there's multiple columns that can be sorted. on top of that there's classes that represent row and classes that represent group. i just wanted to remove sorting when datagrid is grouped.

Comment: this works well enough when implementing the interface for the class that is binding source of the group header. this is actually really good thing cause i don't have to think about different columns. the groupheader is sorted by one property only no matter which column is wanted to be sorted. if someone wants to write an answer that solution is to implement interface for group header's binding source, i'll accept it. even though i asked different question: "How to turn off sorting".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your collections source is a `ObservableCollection<NetObject>` you need to implement the following:

```
public class NetObject : IComparable
{
    // Your Items implementation ....

    public int CompareProperty { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if(!(obj is NetObject)) throw new Exception("The Object can't been compared");

        if (this.CompareProperty > ((NetObject)obj).CompareProperty) return 1;
        if (this.CompareProperty < ((NetObject)obj).CompareProperty) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The `CompareTo`can focus on each of your propertys or fields .... .

The return value shall be:

- **Less than zero:**    This instance precedes obj in the sort order.
- **Zero:**              This instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as obj.
- **Greater than zero:** This instance follows obj in the sort order.

**EDIT:**

In case of `HeaderBindingSource` you could also use:

```
public GroupHeaderBindingSource(string name, string description, GroupHeadersInfo headersInfo) : BindingSource, IGroupHeader, IComparable
{
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if i have 5 columns how do i know which property i should compare? on top of that the DataGrid can already compare them without implementing IComparable. it's grouping that causes the exception.

Comment: I think at least each property you'd like to `group`or `sort by` needs to implement the `ICompareable`. The standard types (such as int doing this). Do you use some properties of other class types (custom classes...)? The `IComparable` implementation in `TestItem` is a kind of default sorting (if no property is chosen). Maybe it is missing and when you: `MyCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.Clear();` the items will been sorted as TestItem is sorted by its `IComparable` implementation.

Comment: I get the same exception even if I don't do MyCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.Clear();  the thing is that I haven't implemented any custom sorting. it is just not disabled in xaml. if nobody can help i just have to disable it in xaml. WPF and especially WPF DataGrid lack all basic/default functionality. grouping shouldn't break sorting.

Comment: this works well enough when implementing the interface for the class that is binding source of the group header. this is actually really good thing cause i don't have to think about different columns. the groupheader is sorted by one property only no matter which column is wanted to be sorted. if someone wants to write an answer that solution is to implement interface for group header's binding source, i'll accept it. even though i asked different question: "How to turn off sorting".

Comment: Could you provide some code of your items class and your CollectionView dependend code? I use Grouping on a sorted DataGrid and have no such problems.

Comment: now it is working! it's working both ungrouped and grouped. only thing that was missing was IComparable implementation for GroupHeaderBindingSource. Moreover this method could always return 0 because no sorting ever happens. Edit your answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the code. As I see you use a List of `NetObject` for your CollectionViewSource. As I interpret the Exception there is no Comparer found at this. Maybe its enough to implement it there.

Comment: Maybe I explained myself wrong, but the solution was to add following lines:   public class GroupHeaderBindingSource : BindingSource, IGroupHeader, IComparable   and  public int CompareTo(object obj) { return 0 } of course CompareTo could be done properly but since it's never really used it doesn't matter.

Comment: I had added these lines at my answer yesterday (above the Items class).